# Generating a global connection in prisma python client

Tags: python, prisma

I'm using Prisma python client for my mysql database. I'm wondering if its possible to do a single global connection instead of having to open and close them whenever I make a query?

```py
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    @commands.slash_command(description="Sets up the server for verification")
    async def help(self, interaction: disnake.GuildCommandInteraction):
        await self.client.prisma.connect()
        response = await self.client.prisma.user.find_first(where={
            "name": "benn",
        })
        print(dict(response))
        await self.client.prisma.disconnect()
```

I tried doing the following:

```py
client.prisma = Prisma(auto_register=True)
async def connect_to_db():
    await client.prisma.connect()

asyncio.run(connect_to_db())
```

However, I get an error:

````py
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: Event loop is closed```
````

Comment: I am so sorry I missed a capital letter in my title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you create one instance of `PrismaClient` and reuse it across your application and you should only set it to a global variable in the development environment only and you do not need to explicitly `$disconnect`. You can learn more about Prisma connection management in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management). Also, I’ll encourage you to ask your Prisma Python client questions in prisma-client-py repositories [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/RobertCraigie/prisma-client-py/discussions)